# Upgrade SSIS package created in SSIS 2014 to work in SSIS 2016

Tags: ssis

How can I upgrade SSIS packages created in SSIS 2014 so that they work in SSIS 2016?

I'm trying to invoke the packages using c# (Package.Execute).
My packages have custom script tasks.

I've written redirects like...

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
```

But I still get the error **To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install  of Integration Services or higher.**

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Documentation - [Understanding the Differences between Local and Remote Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/understanding-the-differences-between-local-and-remote-execution)

> **You can only run a package outside the development environment on a
>   computer that has Integration Services installed**. You cannot run
>   packages outside of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) on a client computer
>   that does not have Integration Services installed, and the terms of
>   your SQL Server licensing may not permit you to install Integration
>   Services on additional computers. SQL Server Integration Services is a
>   server component and is not redistributable to client computers. To
>   run packages from a client computer, you need to launch them in a
>   manner that ensures that the packages run on the server.

So, the C# code calling `Package.Execute` will only work on a machine with SSIS installed.

Please install SSIS on your local development machine to test this code.  Or try [another method to execute packages remotely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/loading-and-running-a-remote-package-programmatically).

- Use SQL Server Agent to run the remote package programmatically
- Use a Web service or remote component to run the remote package
  programmatically

Edit:  Yes, this makes it hard on developers sometimes. Microsoft wants you to pay for that SSIS license.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Troy.
Well actually I meant SSIS 2014 and SSIS 2016. I'm making this correction in my question - my bad!   I believe SSIS 2014 packages dont directly work on an SSIS 2016 engine. So what are the ways to get this to work, especially when I've script tasks and script components (c#)?

Comment: Do you have SQL/SSIS 2016 installed on your development machine?

Comment: Yes.
But my packages have been developed in SSIS 2014. Some of our customers could be on 2016, some still on 2014.

Comment: You have SSIS installed on your local development machine?  Please open SQL Server Configuration Manager and tell me what version of SQL Server Integration Services you are running.  [Image](https://www.mssqltips.com/tipimages2/3086_SQLServer_Configuration_Manager.JPG).  Thanks.

Comment: SSIS 13.0 is the version

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSDT for Visual Studio 2017, you should be able to update the TargetServerVersion option in the properties of the SSIS project.

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh7Gc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps you can take to upgrade SSIS packages created in SSIS 2014 so that they work in SSIS 2016:

1. Open the SSIS package in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio 2015 or later.
2. Save the package in the new format. Go to the File menu and choose Save Copy of [Package Name] As. In the Save Copy of [Package Name] As dialog box, select the SQL Server 2016 option in the Save as type drop-down list.
3. Fix any compatibility issues. If the package has any compatibility issues, you will see them in the Error List window. You may need to update the package to use new or modified components in SSIS 2016.
4. Update connection managers. If your package contains connection managers, you may need to update them to point to the correct server or database.
5. Test the package. After you have made all necessary changes, test the package thoroughly to ensure that it works correctly in SSIS 2016.
6. Deploy the package to the SSIS catalog. Once the package is working correctly in SSIS 2016, deploy it to the SSIS catalog using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

By following these steps, you can upgrade your SSIS packages from SSIS 2014 to SSIS 2016 and ensure that they work correctly in the new version of SSIS.